# Object object error, when trying to get a specific attribute from my Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For each item on my database I need to show a specific property. However, when I run my project were it was supposed to show the content of said property, it shows Object object. I've already tried

```
 console.log(ocorrencia.azimute)
```

and

```
 JSON.stringify(ocorrencia.azimute)
```

Here is my code:

```
 $.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {


        $.each(data, function (i, item) {


            var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                // iterar todas as ocorrencias para tirar delas as imagens


                $.each(item.listaOcorrencias, function (o, ocorrencia) {

                    //ERROR - Object object
                    '<p>Azimute:' + ocorrencia.azimute + '</p>' 

                });

                +'<p></p>' +

            //MORE CODE
            //...


            $('#json map').append(marker);


        }); 
    });
```

It's important to poiny out that my item.listaOcorrencias references an attrbute on my model called ListaOcorrencias, which is a list of data from another model. Here is the model:

public class Ignicoes
    {

```
    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();

    }

  //Other attributes

    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If you are wanting a string representation of the azimute property, you will have to construct it yourself, as it appears it is an object, and by default, objects are strigified as "Object object".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQuery `.each` to iterate over page elements, you need to reference the element using jQuery's `$()`. For example:

```
$.each(item.listaOcorrencias, function (o, ocorrencia) {

// Assuming that 'azimute' is a property of the element
'<p>Azimute:' + $(ocorrencia).azimute + '</p>' 

});
```

If you are iterating over a data array and not page elements, you should use the plain JS `forEach()`.

```
item.listaOcorrencias.forEach( function (ocorrencia, o) {
   '<p>Azimute:' + ocorrencia.azimute + '</p>'
});
```

Comment: it gives me this error: item.listaOcorrencias.foreach is not a function

Comment: @TeresaAlves Sorry, it should be `forEach`. Also, is ``item.listaOcorrencias` an array or an object?

Comment: listaOcorrencias is an array

Comment: Ichanged to forEach and it fixed the previous error, but now instead of appearing Object object it appears undefined

Comment: Can you post an example of what's being passed as "data"?

Comment: `{
    "id": 7023,
    "latitude": "38.726923",
    "longitude": "-9.168225",
    "estado": "aceite",
    "dataInicioPropostaIgnicao": "2020-02-12T20:20:00",
    "dataDecisaoIgnicao": "2020-02-12T20:20:00",
    "listaOcorrencias": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "dispositivo": "LisboaTeste1",
            "dataOcorrencia": "2020-02-12T20:20:00",
            "latitude": "38.726923",
            "longitude": "-9.168225",
            "azimute": "32ºN",
            "fotografia": "fire3.jpg",
            "estado": "aceite"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Is that the output if you `console.log(item)` before `item.listaOcorrencias.forEach( ...` or the value of "data" as it comes into your function? I'm also assuming you've changed  `$.each(data, function (i, item) {` to use `forEach` as well.

Comment: Yes, that's the output before the forEach. And i tried to chanage the first each, however whe I try to put data.forEach(...), it says that it can't read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207790/discussion-between-ed-lucas-and-teresa-alves).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

1.Model:

```
public class Ignicoes
{
    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ign { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }
}
public class Ocorrencias
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Azimute { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
<div id="json">
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                console.log(item);           
                var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="' + i + '">' +
                    '</div>';

                $('#json').append(infowindow);

                $.each(item.listaOcorrencias, function (o, ocorrencia) {
                    console.log(ocorrencia.azimute)

                    $("#" + i).append('<p>Azimute:' + ocorrencia.azimute + '</p>');
                });        
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
public ActionResult<List<Ignicoes>> IgnicoesAPI()
{
    var model = new List<Ignicoes>()
    {
        new Ignicoes(){ 
            Id=1,Ign="I1", 
            ListaOcorrencias = new List<Ocorrencias>(){ 
                new Ocorrencias() { Id=1,Azimute="O1" }, 
                new Ocorrencias() { Id=2,Azimute="O2" }
            } },
        new Ignicoes(){
            Id=1,Ign="I2",
            ListaOcorrencias = new List<Ocorrencias>(){
                new Ocorrencias() { Id=3,Azimute="O3" },
                new Ocorrencias() { Id=4,Azimute="O4" },
                new Ocorrencias() { Id=5,Azimute="O5" }
            } },
    };
    return model;
}
```

4.Result:

[image]